# Java compare SHA-256 hashed string with a password clear text string

Tags: java, arrays, sha256

I am trying an example:

```
String hashAlgorithm ="sha-256"
...
md=MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
byte[] enteredPasswordDigest = md.digest(policy.getPassword().getBytes());
if (!MessageDigest.isEqual(enteredPasswordDigest, realPassword.getBytes())) {
    ...
}
```

However, the hashed password is stored as a string in the database. When I do that comparison, it fails. When I debug it, `enteredPasswordDigest` has 32 byte length and `realPassword.getBytes()` has 64 byte length.

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you sure the the length of realPassword.getBytes() is 64 bit (=8 byte) not byte? Because I don't know a secure hash function that would create an 64 bit output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question with that point: Hashed password as a string at database is **"hex"**. That is the main point. So I got the hex of entered password's byte array digest. Then I compared strings that has hex values.

Comment: Now that you've managed what you were looking for, you may want to consider looking at salting it for better security.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

- take the entered password and hash/digest it
- convert the `byte[]` to string
- compare that string to the already-hashed-password string in the DB

Try this,

```
String hashedStr = new String(enteredPasswordDigest);
if (!hashedStr.equals(realPassword)) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

**Docs:** `String.getBytes()`

> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the
>   default charset is unspecified.  The `java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder`
>   class should be used when more control over the encoding process is
>   required.

Comment: hashedStr's length is 32 but realPassword is 64?

Comment: @kamaci: `realPassword.getBytes().length` is 64, I'm not using that. Just use the string `realPassword`itself, as shown in my post. And the length of that is indeed 32.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming realPassword is a String, the problem might be that Java strings are UTF16, ie 2 bytes per character. Try printing both byte arrays to get a better insight in whats going on.